# apache rewrite rule for url's when no query is used

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I have the following rewrite rule that I want to use when an user accesses the website like **www.domain.com/home.php**. It redirects him to the root.

`RewriteRule ^home\.php / [R=301,L]`

However, I don't want it to use when a query (`domain.com/home.php?var1=999`) is used. How make it only apply for urls without a query string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a rewrite condition that checks that query string is empty.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^home\.php / [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Add rule condition with QUERY_STRING ( RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ) before the rule.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString